# Is there an equivalent of Ruby's instance_eval in Swift?

Tags: swift

In ruby I can pass a block into a method and have the block evaluated in the context of the receiving object.

```
class Receiver

    def method_a
        puts "hello from method_a"
    end

    def method_b
        puts "hello from method_b"
    end

    def define_something &action
        method_a 
        instance_eval &action
    end

end

thing = Receiver.new 
thing.define_something { method_b }
```

which produces the following output:

```
hello from method_a
hello from method_b
```

Whats the right way to implement something like this in Swift?

Here is what I have, but of course Xcode complains that `methodB` is an unresolved identifier.

```
class Receiver {

    func methodA() {
        print("hello from method A")
    }

    func methodB() {
        print("hello from method B")
    }

    func defineSomething( action: () -> Void ) {
        methodA()
        action()
    }
}

let thing = Receiver()
thing.defineSomething { methodB() }
```

BTW, this can also be done in Kotlin which has the idea of a function type with a receiver.

for example the following produces similar output to what the ruby example produces.

```
class Receiver {
   fun methodA() = println("hello from methodA")
   fun methodB() = println("hello from methodB")
   fun defineSomething( action: Receiver.() -> Unit) {
       methodA()
       action()
   }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   val thing = Receiver()
   thing.defineSomething { methodB() }
}

hello from methodA
hello from methodB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do that in the language.  You can do it manually by having `action` take a `Receiver` instance as input, and then call `action(self)` inside of `defineSomething(action:)`.

```
class Receiver {

    func methodA() {
        print("hello from method A")
    }

    func methodB() {
        print("hello from method B")
    }

    func defineSomething(action: (_: Receiver) -> Void ) {
        methodA()
        action(self)
    }
}

let thing = Receiver()
thing.defineSomething { $0.methodB() }
```

> ```
>  hello from method A
>  hello from method B
> ```

Comment: I believe that most languages are more than happy to just call `thing.defineSomething { thing.methodB() }` which does exactly the same but is much simpler. Could be also implemented by passing a `#selector`.

Comment: I was thinking about this from an internal DSL implementation.  Both solutions would be functional,  but it's not really very elegant  having to have a prefix for the methods.

Comment: Swift is still evolving.  This is something that could/should be added in a future release.

Comment: I agree,  it would be a nice addition to the language.